# AdMob Native Ads in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, admob

I'm not having very good luck getting AdMob Native Ads to work with SwiftUI. I tried to use the code found [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/blob/master/Swift/admob/NativeAdvancedExample/NativeAdvancedExample/ViewController.swift).

This is the exact code I ended up with because much of the code from that link wouldn't work:

```swift
import GoogleMobileAds
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // The view that holds the native ad.
    @IBOutlet var nativeAdPlaceholder: UIView!
    
    // The height constraint applied to the ad view, where necessary.
    var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    
    // The ad loader. You must keep a strong reference to the GADAdLoader
    // during the ad loading process.
    var adLoader: GADAdLoader!
    
    // The native ad view that is being presented.
    var nativeAdView: GADUnifiedNativeAdView!
    
    // The ad unit ID.
    let adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3986624511"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard let nibObjects = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("UnifiedNativeAdView", owner: nil, options: nil),
              let adView = nibObjects.first as? GADUnifiedNativeAdView
        else {
            assert(false, "Could not load nib file for adView")
        }
        setAdView(adView)
        refreshAd(nil)
    }
    
    func setAdView(_ adView: GADUnifiedNativeAdView) {
        // Remove the previous ad view.
        nativeAdView = adView
        nativeAdPlaceholder = UIView()
        nativeAdPlaceholder.addSubview(nativeAdView)
        nativeAdView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // Layout constraints for positioning the native ad view to stretch the entire width and height
        // of the nativeAdPlaceholder.
        let viewDictionary = ["_nativeAdView": nativeAdView!]
        nativeAdPlaceholder.addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
                withVisualFormat: "H:|[_nativeAdView]|",
                options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), 
                metrics: nil, 
                views: viewDictionary
            )
        )
        nativeAdPlaceholder.addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
                withVisualFormat: "V:|[_nativeAdView]|",
                options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), 
                metrics: nil, 
                views: viewDictionary
            )
        )
    }
    
    // MARK: - Actions
    // Refreshes the native ad.
    @IBAction func refreshAd(_ sender: AnyObject!) {
        adLoader = GADAdLoader(
            adUnitID: adUnitID, rootViewController: self,
            adTypes: [.unifiedNative], options: nil)
        adLoader.delegate = self
        adLoader.load(GADRequest())
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: GADUnifiedNativeAdLoaderDelegate {
    func adLoader(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
        print("fail")
    }
    
    func adLoader(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader, didReceive nativeAd: GADUnifiedNativeAd) {
        
        // Set ourselves as the native ad delegate to be notified of native ad events.
        nativeAd.delegate = self
        
        // Deactivate the height constraint that was set when the previous video ad loaded.
        heightConstraint?.isActive = false
        
        // Populate the native ad view with the native ad assets.
        // The headline and mediaContent are guaranteed to be present in every native ad.
        (nativeAdView.headlineView as? UILabel)?.text = nativeAd.headline
        nativeAdView.mediaView?.mediaContent = nativeAd.mediaContent
        
        // This app uses a fixed width for the GADMediaView and changes its height to match the aspect
        // ratio of the media it displays.
        if let mediaView = nativeAdView.mediaView, nativeAd.mediaContent.aspectRatio > 0 {
            heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: mediaView,
                attribute: .height,
                relatedBy: .equal,
                toItem: mediaView,
                attribute: .width,
                multiplier: CGFloat(1 / nativeAd.mediaContent.aspectRatio),
                constant: 0)
            heightConstraint?.isActive = true
        }
        
        // These assets are not guaranteed to be present. Check that they are before
        // showing or hiding them.
        (nativeAdView.bodyView as? UILabel)?.text = nativeAd.body
        nativeAdView.bodyView?.isHidden = nativeAd.body == nil
        
        (nativeAdView.callToActionView as? UIButton)?.setTitle(nativeAd.callToAction, for: .normal)
        nativeAdView.callToActionView?.isHidden = nativeAd.callToAction == nil
        
        (nativeAdView.iconView as? UIImageView)?.image = nativeAd.icon?.image
        nativeAdView.iconView?.isHidden = nativeAd.icon == nil
        
        nativeAdView.starRatingView?.isHidden = true
        
        (nativeAdView.storeView as? UILabel)?.text = nativeAd.store
        nativeAdView.storeView?.isHidden = nativeAd.store == nil
        
        (nativeAdView.priceView as? UILabel)?.text = nativeAd.price
        nativeAdView.priceView?.isHidden = nativeAd.price == nil
        
        (nativeAdView.advertiserView as? UILabel)?.text = nativeAd.advertiser
        nativeAdView.advertiserView?.isHidden = nativeAd.advertiser == nil
        
        // In order for the SDK to process touch events properly, user interaction should be disabled.
        nativeAdView.callToActionView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        
        // Associate the native ad view with the native ad object. This is
        // required to make the ad clickable.
        // Note: this should always be done after populating the ad views.
        nativeAdView.nativeAd = nativeAd
    }
}

// MARK: - GADUnifiedNativeAdDelegate implementation
extension ViewController: GADUnifiedNativeAdDelegate {
    
    func nativeAdDidRecordClick(_ nativeAd: GADUnifiedNativeAd) {
        print("\(#function) called")
    }
    
    func nativeAdDidRecordImpression(_ nativeAd: GADUnifiedNativeAd) {
        print("\(#function) called")
    }
    
    func nativeAdWillPresentScreen(_ nativeAd: GADUnifiedNativeAd) {
        print("\(#function) called")
    }
    
    func nativeAdWillDismissScreen(_ nativeAd: GADUnifiedNativeAd) {
        print("\(#function) called")
    }
    
    func nativeAdDidDismissScreen(_ nativeAd: GADUnifiedNativeAd) {
        print("\(#function) called")
    }
    
    func nativeAdWillLeaveApplication(_ nativeAd: GADUnifiedNativeAd) {
        print("\(#function) called")
    }
}
```

And I made this struct:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct NativeViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let picker = ViewController()
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

But when I put that `NativeViewController` in the body like so:

```swift
var body: some View {
    NativeViewController()
}
```

I get no errors but also no ad displayed.

Any direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this was to use self.view instead of the placeholder code

```
    // Remove the previous ad view.
    nativeAdView = adView
    self.view.addSubview(nativeAdView)
    nativeAdView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    // Layout constraints for positioning the native ad view to stretch the entire width and height
    // of the nativeAdPlaceholder.
    let viewDictionary = ["_nativeAdView": nativeAdView!]
    self.view.addConstraints(
      NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:|[_nativeAdView]|",
        options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary)
    )
    self.view.addConstraints(
      NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "V:|[_nativeAdView]|",
        options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary)
    )
```

Comment: Hi, I am facing a similar issue with the ads not showing up (using the test native ads). There isn't a lot of documentation/examples involving SwiftUI. How were you able to get it to show up?
I tried using your code exactly except for one change where since I don't use storyboards, I just did:
let nibView = GADUnifiedNativeAdView()
setAdView(nibView)
refreshAd(nil)

I see the little google ad logo in the top right corner, but nothing shows up. I see in the Xcode console: nativeAdDidRecordImpression(_:) called
so it seems like the code is working, but the ad is not showing up. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3129120 If you don't use the storyboards in Google's example, you will have to create your own UIView class that extends GADUnifiedNativeAdView. If you simple just use `let nibView = GADUnifiedNativeAdView()` without the storyboard integration, properties like `nativeAdView.bodyView` should be nil.

Comment: @user3129120 did you resolve it ? I have the exact same issue ...

Comment: Hey, I didn't really solve it. But I realized I didn't need Native ads. I just needed SwiftUI Banner ads and those worked well. There are examples of those ready to use. Like this for example: https://medium.com/@michaelbarneyjr/how-to-integrate-admob-ads-in-swiftui-fbfd3d774c50

Comment: @user3129120 thanks, I found today this working example if you or anyone else will be still interested in how to make native ads work, specifically that NIB part:
https://github.com/sakurabird/iOS-Admob-SwiftUI-example//

Answer (score 1):

Google now provides [SwiftUI samples](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/tree/main/Swift/advanced/SwiftUIDemo/SwiftUIDemo) for AdMob integration.

Note that:

- You have native ad sample files in the **Native** directory in the GitHub repo above ([here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/tree/main/Swift/advanced/SwiftUIDemo/SwiftUIDemo/Native)).
- You have remaining files in the **Supporting-Files** directory in the same repo ([here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/tree/main/Swift/advanced/SwiftUIDemo/SwiftUIDemo/Supporting-Files)).
- Most of the relevant code is in the `NativeContentView.swift` file ([here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/blob/main/Swift/advanced/SwiftUIDemo/SwiftUIDemo/Native/NativeContentView.swift)).
- Native ad design may be problematic depending on how much you want to customize it. See below.

---

#### No customization

If you want to use the default design provided in the sample:

1. Download the XIB file from the repo
2. Place the file in the desired directory.
3. Add it to your project through `File > Add Files to ...` (or **Opt + Cmd + A**).

---

#### Partial or full customization

If you want to create your own NIB:

1. Go to `File > New > File` (or **Cmd + N**) and select `View` under User Interface.
2. Start adding your views.
3. IBOutlets are broken. You will need to quickly replicate the Objective-C header file:

   1. With the NIB open, go to `Editor > Assistant` (or **Ctrl + Opt + Cmd + Return**).
   2. In the Assistant, navigate to `Class > GADNativeAd.h`.
   3. Copy everything.
   4. Go to `File > New > File` (or **Cmd + N**) and select `Header File`.
   5. Name the file `GADNativeAdTemp`.
   6. Under `#define GADNativeAdTemp_h`, paste the code you copied a few steps back.
   7. Under import statements, add `#import <GADNativeAdTemp.h>`.
   8. If you open the NIB now and select the `Native Ad View`, you should finally be able to see the outlets and link to them.
   9. After you're done linking to outlets, delete the `GADNativeAdTemp.h` file.
4. Depending on which views you implement, remember to adjust the `updateUIView` function in the `NativeAdView` struct.

---

If at any point you want to revert to the NIB design from the repo:

1. With the file open, enable code review by clicking the button in the top-right corner of the editor.

[image: Enable Code Review button]

2. Paste the XML from `NativeAdView.xib` in the repo ([here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/blob/main/Swift/advanced/SwiftUIDemo/SwiftUIDemo/Native/NativeAdView.xib)).
3. Click the same button to switch back to the graphical editor.

Answer (score -2):

The best approach is to create a delegate class where its instance is in the view where the AD will be shown.

Create a delegate (here with the dummy test ad):

```
let interstitialID:String = "/6499/example/interstitial"

final class InterstitialDelegate: NSObject, GADInterstitialDelegate {
    
    var interstitial: DFPInterstitial!
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }
    
    func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> DFPInterstitial {
        interstitial = DFPInterstitial(adUnitID: interstitialID)
        interstitial.delegate = self
        interstitial.load(DFPRequest())
        return interstitial
    }
    
    func showAd() {
        print("Request to show AD")
        if self.interstitial.isReady {
            let root = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
            self.interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: root!)
            print("AD presented")
        } else {
            print("AD not ready")
        }
    }
    
    private func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: DFPInterstitial) {
        interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }
}
```

Then in the view where the ad should show up create an instance of the delegate above:

```
struct MainView: View {
        
    var interstitial : InterstitialDelegate

    init() {
        interstitial = InterstitialDelegate()
    }

}
```

Then within this view request an AD by calling

```
interstitial.showAd()
```

for example after the user has listened to music.

Credit: https://medium.com/@michaelbarneyjr/how-to-integrate-admob-ads-in-swiftui-fbfd3d774c50 who's also mentioned above in the answer by @pawello2222 and then I've updated it with the info from [Google's Mobile Ads SDK](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/ios/interstitial).

Comment: OP asked for native ad!