# Adding admob Native Ads in SwiftUI project?

Tags: swiftui, admob

I'm trying to add a Native Admob Ad in my swiftui project.

I can add banners Ads easily using the following code but not Native Ads!

```
struct GADBannerViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let view = GADBannerView(adSize: GADAdSizeBanner)
        let viewController = UIViewController()
        view.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5135589807"
        view.rootViewController = viewController
        viewController.view.addSubview(view)
        viewController.view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: GADAdSizeBanner.size)
        view.load(GADRequest())
        return viewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {}
}
```

and then I show the banner ad like so:

```
    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        GADBannerViewController()
                            .frame(width: GADAdSizeBanner.size.width, height: GADAdSizeBanner.size.height)
                        Spacer()
                    }.ba

ckground(Color.red)
```

Anyone knows how to show Native ads in SwiftUI?

For some reason every information available is for adding Banner ads or Interstitial ads!! Nothing about NATIVE Ads!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Admob Native Ads in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63642495/admob-native-ads-in-swiftui)