# How to implement Google native ads in Flutter using iOS SwiftUI instead of XIB?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, admob, xib

I haven't worked with XIB files before. I only used Swift `View` to create UI in iOS. However, the documentation of Flutter native ads for iOS provides only examples with XIB files ([here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/native/advanced#code_example)).

How can I create UI with SwiftUI instead of XIB files for this?

Currently, it uses this in `AppDelegate` class to load `nativeAdFactory`:

```swift
let listTileFactory = PageAd()
FLTGoogleMobileAdsPlugin.registerNativeAdFactory(self, 
                                                 factoryId: "listTile", 
                                                 nativeAdFactory: listTileFactory)
```

and the `PageAd` data in XIB like this:

```swift
class PageAd: FLTNativeAdFactory {
    func createNativeAd(_ nativeAd: GADNativeAd,
                        customOptions: [AnyHashable : Any]? = nil) -> GADNativeAdView? {
        let nibView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PageAdUi", owner: nil, options: nil)!.first
        let nativeAdView = nibView as! GADNativeAdView
            
        (nativeAdView.headlineView as! UILabel).text = nativeAd.headline
            
        (nativeAdView.bodyView as! UILabel).text = nativeAd.body
        nativeAdView.bodyView!.isHidden = nativeAd.body == nil
            
        (nativeAdView.iconView as! UIImageView).image = nativeAd.icon?.image
        nativeAdView.iconView!.isHidden = nativeAd.icon == nil
            
        (nativeAdView.iconView as! UIImageView).image = nativeAd.icon?.image
        nativeAdView.iconView!.isHidden = nativeAd.icon == nil
            
        nativeAdView.callToActionView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            
        nativeAdView.nativeAd = nativeAd
            
        return nativeAdView
    }
}
```

So, I am trying something like this, but I don't know how to call this in `AppDelegate`.

```swift
struct ContentView: GADNativeAdView {
    var nativeAdView : GADNativeAd;

    func ContentView(_ nativeAd: GADNativeAd, customOptions: [AnyHashable : Any]? = nil) {
        nativeAdView = nativeAd
    }
        
    var body: some View {
        Text(nativeAdView.headline)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to mix SwiftUI and UIKit the only way to interface these is with `UIViewController` or `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Admob Native Ads in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63642495/admob-native-ads-in-swiftui)